# I want to plot multiple histogram per site

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want 4 histograms on the x axis; one for each Site with bins for each group of individuals. The groups are ; "mol","an","crust" and "other". the y axis would be the mean abundance.
the data frame can be called DF.

|  | mol | an | crust | other | Site |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00000 | 0.0000000 | 12.000000 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 0.00000 | 0.6666667 | 28.000000 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 0.00000 | 0.3333333 | 2.000000 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 4.00000 | 1.3333333 | 3.000000 | 0 | 4 |
| 5 | 12.66667 | 3.3333333 | 1.666667 | 0 | 5 |

ggplot(DF, aes(fill=?, y=?, x=Site)) +
geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")

I am lost in want to put in sections fill= and y=, I have been doing it seperetly with vectors and it worked but would like to group all. DF$Site differs from another "Site" I have been using for my simpler histograms:
Site  <- c(rep("1" , 1) , rep("2" , 1) , rep("3", 1) , rep("4" , 1), rep("5" , 1) )

And I would "fill" with:   fill = rep("whatever",5)

for my means I would creat a vector and plug into y=  like so: mol = c(1,0,0,4,12.66666667)
I would also use the mean vector with a standard deviation vector for the error bars:

sdmol = c(0.471404521,0,0,5.656854249,16.51934892)

+geom_errorbar( aes(x=Site, ymin=mol-sdmol, ymax= mol+sdmol), width=0.4, colour="orange", alpha=0.9, size=1)+theme(text=element_text(size=20))

I can regroup all my data if it helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(mol, an, crust)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Site), y=value, fill=name))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

OR

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(mol, an, crust)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Site, y=value, fill=name))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(.~Site, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the first one is very good thank you! How would I add error bars if my standard errors are in the same data frame as columns?

Comment: How would I add error bars if my standard errors are in the same data frame as columns?

Comment: Just add somthing like this to ggplot: `geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))`.

Comment: Do I have to do it for all standard deviation columns? I have one column for each factor